# How to make the input param optional in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

The is my serializer.py and I want to make image as an optional field which means either there's an uploaded image or null. But even though I set up required false for image, when sending the POST request it will still ask for image and gives the error of no im

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Class Meta:
       model = User
       field = ('name', 'division', 'image',)
       extra_kwargs = {'image': {'required': False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        newUser = User.objects.create(
           name = validated_data['name'],
           division = validated_data['division']
           image = validated_data['image']
        )
        return newUser;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `image` in the model *nullable*?

Comment: set **`null=True`** in ***`image`*** field of **`User`** then, migrate the DB